# How To Clear Heroku logs

Tags: heroku, command-line

There is another question here with the same topic but has not been answered properly, that's why I'm asking it again, the information in the answer is old and innacurate.

For example, `heroku restart` will **not** clear the logs and when running in Production mode it's not something you can do.

Is there any way to clear them at all?

Comment: What would be the point of doing that ?

Comment: I am curious as to why do you want to clear them?  Heroku only holds the most recent 1500 lines.

Comment: It's just a lot easier to troubleshoot Sidekiq, Redis, Mysql connections, etc problems if you start off with a fresh log and not have to read the old ones for every test I run. It gets really confusing, especially after you've been hours at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearing the logs is not functionality that Heroku provide.

Comment: Couldn't you purge all events, or uninstall and reinstall your logging app? This clears all the viewable log data when accessed via the Heroku website. Or is this not the same as actually clearing the Heroku logs?